# Search Query Problems: Won't display Instructors when Check Box Unticked

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

```
+--------------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| InstructorID | CourseID | Course date |    Type    | Pass or Fail? |
+--------------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
|        00001 |        1 | 22/05/2007  | Assessment | True          |
|        00001 |        2 | 01/02/2012  | Assessment | True          |
|        00001 |        3 | 21/08/2015  | Training   | True          |
|        00001 |        3 | 21/06/2016  | Assessment | False         |
|        00001 |        4 | 21/03/2013  | Assessment | True          |
|        00001 |       11 | 10/10/2014  | Training   | True          |
|        00004 |        3 | 20/01/1975  | Assessment | True          |
|        00100 |        1 | 25/05/2005  | Assessment | True          |
|        00100 |        5 | 12/12/1999  | Assessment | True          |
|        22222 |        1 | 07/05/2013  | Training   | True          |
|        22222 |        9 | 08/05/2015  | Assessment | False         |
|        22222 |       10 | 04/06/2015  | Assessment | True          |
|        22222 |       12 | 14/05/2014  | Assessment | True          |
+--------------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

I have a certain query which refers to this table with the type and Pass or Fail?. What happens is that i have a search page with a combo box and a check box and a button, when the button is pressed, it will search for the activity in the combo box, and then will search for the pass or fail is true or not, and then if the type is 'assessment' or 'training'. It would be training when the check box is unticked as they are not technically qualified, but when ticked it should only display instructors  that are qualified for canoeing, have assessment, and pass or fail is true.

10,11,12 are the ID of the 3 canoeing courses.

My Query that will produce the Qualified:

```
IIf([Forms]![Find Activity Instructors]![Check4]=True,IIf([Pass or Fail?]=True,[Type]="Assessment",IIf([Forms]![Find Activity Instructors]![Check4]=False,IIf([Pass or Fail?]=True,[Type]="Training",[Pass or Fail?]=False))))
```

So my question is, why won't the instructor in training appear when the combo box is selected as canoeing?

Screenies:

https://snag.gy/jFru12.jpg  Query Screen

https://snag.gy/1HWImy.jpg Search Screen

https://snag.gy/CFIGJi.jpg What appears when Combo is Canoeing and Check box is True

https://snag.gy/TO9ZiA.jpg What happens when combo is canoeing and Check Box is False

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the IIf()'s are nested, `IIf([Forms]![Find Activity Instructors]![Check4]=False,IIf([Pass or Fail?]=True,[Type]="Training",[Pass or Fail?]=False` only runs if the first test of [Pass or Fail!] is false.

You don't show any records where Training has [Pass or Fail?] = False - could there be? Consider:

> WHERE [Category]=[Forms]![Find Activity Instructors]![Category] AND [Type]=IIf([Forms]![Find Activity Instructors]![Check4]=True, "Assessment","Training") AND [Pass or Fail?]=True

I never use dynamic parameters in queries. I prefer code behind form that constructs filter criteria and then applies to form or report.

Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore is exception) in names. Better would be [IsPassed] or [Is_Passed].